# C++ static member variable scope

Tags: c++, scope, static-members

The title basically says it all, i wonder when static members of a c++ class are initialized and when they go out of scope.

I need this for the following problem. I have many objects of a class Foo and each object needs access to a resource, encapsulated by another class Bar. Synchronization is not an issue, so i want all objects to share the same Bar instance.

I'm using a simple managed pointer for reference counting.

Can i do the following:

```
class Foo {
private:
    static managed_pointer<Bar> staticBar;
public:
    Foo() {
        if(!staticBar)
            staticBar = new Bar;
    }
    /*
     * use staticBar in various non-static member functions
     */
};

managed_pointer<Bar> Foo::staticBar = NULL;
```

the managed_pointer staticBar should delete the Bar object as soon as it goes out of scope - but when does this happen? when the last instance of Foo is destructed? on application exit?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: oops, thanks for fixing the typo.

Comment: The last instance of Foo is destructed when you simply delete the last instance or when your program exists. A static member of a class will exist no matter how many instances of the class there are.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`static`s and globals are initialized right before the program starts (before `main` is called, the program actually starts before that) and go out of scope after `main` exits.

Exceptions - local statics (static variables declared inside functions) and unused template class `static`members.

It has nothing to do with the number of instances.

Comment: Local static variables are not initialized before the program starts.

Comment: ok thanks. What do you mean by "It has nothing to do with the number of instances"? Instances of class Foo?

Comment: yes it does not matter how many instances of Foo there is, they will all share Bar.

Comment: @Gabi nor unused static members if the class is a template.

Comment: @LeSnip3R: yes of course, that's the intention, otherwise i could just make `Bar` a non-static member and let `Foo`s ctor and dtor take care of allocating/deleting `Bar`.

Comment: *`static` and globals are initialized right before the program starts* is misleading. The program starts *before* initialization is done (program starts well before `main`), **and**, it is unspecified whether variables with static duration are initialized *before* the first statement in `main` is executed. The guarantee is that initialization must be performed *before* the first *odr-use* of the static.

Comment: Class static variables are out of scope outside of the class definition (or its derived classes) and class member definitions (and definitions of derived class members). This is not the same as when their lifetime ends.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas that's what I meant. But I don't know of any implementation that initializes statics after entering main but before use.

Comment: What happens if the code is not for a program with a `main()` function but for a dynamic library?

Comment: @Daniel is the dynamic library loaded when the program starts, or dynamically (LoadLibrary)?

Comment: I wasn't aware that this makes a difference. Personally, I am asking about a C++ module for Python—so I guess it's the second case: the library is not loaded immediately when the Python interpreter starts but when the module is imported in the Python code. However, if someone had a universal answer, that would be all the better.

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not specify a precise order of initialization, it is implementation specific. They will be instantiated at the start of the program and deallocated at the end.

You have to be very careful with what you are doing, because if you have some other static objects that rely on this object to exist, it's UB. There is no telling in what order they will be initialized.

You could possibly look into something like boost::call_once to ensure it's initialized once, but I wouldn't rely on the order the statics are initialized.

For all I know, you code would work, but I've been bitten by the static initialization issue before so I wanted to warn you.

EDIT: Also in your code, when the managed_ptr will go out of scope (end of program), it will delete the memory allocated automatically. But you should not do anything non-trivial in Bar's destructor as you may trigger UB by calling into other free'd instances or even code that has been removed (as it happened to me once where a dynamic library had been removed). Essentially you are in a minefield, so watch out.

Comment: I won't have any other `static`s in Foo, but thanks for the warning, another detail good to have in mind. EDIT: thank you also for the second warning, I'll watch out.

Comment: I meant, other static objects in your *program*. If later on you decide to have another object, say ReBar, that is also static, and you think "hey I can call Bar::Something since it's static" you ought to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that pops out of your question is the common misconception that *scope* and *lifetime* are equivalent concepts. They are not. In some cases as with local variables, the *lifetime* is bound to a particular *context*, but that is not always the case.

A class static member variable has *class scope* (it is accessible *anywhere* in the program) and *static lifetime*, which means that it will be initialized in order with respect to the other static variables in the same translation unit, and in an undefined order with respect to other static variables in other translation units, *before* main (caveat: initialization need not be performed before the first statement in main, but it is guaranteed to be before the first *odr-use* of the variable).

Comment: A class static member variable has _class_ scope: it is only visible in contexts where names are looked up within the class.  It has static lifetime, and external binding (a third concept which people occasionally confuse with the two you mention).  Still, you've mentioned the essential point: lifetime and scope are orthogonal concepts.  (At least to a degree.  There _are_ cases where the scope determines the lifetime.)